# Internal Server Error during migration to mysql-django-uwsgi-nginx

Tags: python, mysql, django, sqlite, nginx

I've have been following this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-django-applications-with-uwsgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04)

However I decided to migrate to mysql database but all I get is an Internal Server Error text on main page and usually you get from django very accurate explanation why did error occurred (yes DEBUG = True).

If I switch back to sqlite in settings.py it works again but I don't think sqlite is for production so I need different db like mysql.

Do you know why this error happens or at least where can I find error log?
I'm loosing my mind to crack this. I know that problem is with mysql but where!

I tried to check did I install what i need:

```
sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev
sudo pip3 install mysqlclient
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

but they are already instaled

I tried to reset instances:

```
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl restart uwsgi
sudo nginx -t && sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

I tried to set up different settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',#or mysql.connector.django
        'NAME': 'db',
        'USER':'username',
        'PASSWORD':'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost', # or ip-address where the site is hosted
        'PORT': '3306', # or ''
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happen to me ones since I used same tutorial as you. The main reason that could happen is because you didn't activate your virtual environment and install `pip install mysqlclient`. Ones you installed it and restarted uwsgi it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you run migrate after you changed your database?

```
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Yes I did sudo -H python3 manage.py makemigrations and sudo -H manage.py migrate... Does it make difference if I do that with or without activating virtualenv?